# how to prove the image of a loop is the entire space

Tags: algebraic-topology, winding-number, loop-spaces

Show that there exists a loop $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow S^2$ such that the image of $\gamma$ is the entire $S^2$

i cannot prove it in a exactly correctly way, could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you familiar with [space filling curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: think of the space-filling curve (which is a famous example in topology).

Comment: sorry, I still cannot solve it, could you help me to show it in details?

Answer (score 0):

The *Peano curve* in particular,  or *space-filling curves* in general,  are examples of this type of  phenomenon...

See if you can transfer these ideas to the sphere...

(Since $S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2\cup \infty $ you are well on your way. ..)

For example,  you should be able to find a curve from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R^2$.  Then for your loop, $\gamma $, extend by mapping $0$ and $1$ to the north pole (point at infinity)